# converting filterXPATH result to text

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to extract the title text from an html page and insert it into an object. I am using symphony and php. The result from `filterXPATH` does not seem to be plain text and instead it is the entire html page and throwing error. I don't know why.

My code is:

```
$html =  $this->file_get_contents_curl("http://www.google.com/");
$urlData = [];
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$urlData->title = $crawler->filterXPath('//title')->extract('_text');
```

I see the title text if I do:

```
return $crawler->filterXPath('//title')->extract('_text');
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error: Attempt to assign property of non-object

Comment: Specifically here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26572398/367456

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html =  file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/");
$dom1 = new DOMDocument;
$dom1->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom1->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom1);
$xp->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$urlData= $xp->query('//title');
foreach($urlData as $title) {
echo $title->textContent;
}
```

Comment: I need to assign $title (which should be plain text string) into $data->title. When I try to do it it is giving the same error. Appreciate the help